# use pandas to get 3 years average in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a table from different companies' sales.

```
company_name sales  year
    A         200   2019
    A         100   2018
    A         30    2017
    A         20    2016
    A         18    2015
    B         15    2019
    B         30    2018
    B         45    2017
    B         120   2016
    B         100   2015
```

Now, I want to add a previous year's sales in the same row just like. How to get it?

```
company_name sales  year   past_3_years_average
    A         200   2019       110
    A         100   2018       50
    A         30    2017       20        
    A         20    2016       Nan
    A         10    2015       Nan
    B         15    2019       30
    B         30    2018       66.6
    B         45    2017       90
    B         125   2016       Nan 
    B         100   2015       Nan
```

Comment: your data changes for `A 2015`. Input is 18 v/s output is 10 also for `B 2017` , the mean is not 90. `(45+125+100)/3 = 88.33` can you please let me know if they are real or made up numbers

Comment: sorry i meant input `(45+120+100)/3 = 88.33`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try rolling

```
df['past_3_years_average'] = df.sort_values(['company_name','year']).groupby('company_name').sales.rolling(3).mean().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)

df
Out[106]: 
  company_name  sales  year  past_3_years_average
0            A    200  2019            110.000000
1            A    100  2018             50.000000
2            A     30  2017             20.000000
3            A     20  2016                   NaN
4            A     10  2015                   NaN
5            B     15  2019             30.000000
6            B     30  2018             66.666667
7            B     45  2017             90.000000
8            B    125  2016                   NaN
9            B    100  2015                   NaN
```